# Rails - Issue with passenger and mysql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

My Rails app currently runs on Passenger. We have six machines in production with each machine having 45 instances of passenger. Each instance of Passenger seems to be having a open connection with MySQL. So there are about 270 open connections with MySQL.

A few minutes after the application is started MySQL seems to at 400% CPU and the application almost becomes non-responsive with a lot of pending requests in the global queue.

Prior to this release the application was running on Mongrel (six machines with each machine running 5 instances of mongrel). We did not see any issues there.

Will reducing the number of Passenger instances solve the issue? Is there a way we can have a connection pool for the passenger instances (Instead of each instance having a separate connection).

Thanks,
Sivakumar

Comment: What kind of machines are you running on? Are they VPS'? RAM? CPU?

Comment: I mean physical machine with its own CPU and RAM

Comment: I meant to ask: How much RAM? How fast are the CPUs? How many cores etc...

Comment: Each machine has two processors each having 4 cores

Comment: And each machine has 16GB of RAM

Comment: Much probably. Each Passenger instance spawns multiple workers, are you counting those in? I think the best approach is one passenger instance (spawn sever) and to configure it with one worker for each core (it may vary a little).

Answer (score 0):

Passenger shares db connections among all processes. Make sure your database.yml has a high pool size.

[passenger-hosted-rails-app-painfully](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2200586/passenger-hosted-rails-app-painfully-slow-but-the-server-is-a-beast)

Comment: For posterity's sake, I want to note that this may not be true.  See [this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phusion-passenger/hfdeaysTqPo).